# How to pass model from view to controller in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, view, controller

I have a controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/manage/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView goManage(@PathVariable int id) {
    UserAccount userAccount = userAccountService.findUserAccount(id);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("admin/manage");
    mav.addObject("userAccount", userAccount);
    return mav;
}
```

and i pass userAccount model to manage.jsp view. In view I display this model. Example:

```
<div id="info">
    <label>Login:</label><label>${userAccount.userDto.username}</label><br />
    <label>Name:</label><label>${userAccount.userDto.firstName}
        ${userAccount.userDto.lastName}</label>
</div>
    <form:form
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/go"
        modelAttribute="userAccount" method="post">
        <input class="myButton" type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form:form>
```

And it's ok, but I want pass this model userAccount from view further to next controller when I clicked button Go. My above form implementation doesen't work. How I can pass object from view? It's possible?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/go", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView goWithDrawalInvestment(
        @ModelAttribute("userAccount") UserAccount userAccount) {
        userAccount.setBalance(0);
        mav.addObject("userAccount", userAccountDto);
        return mav;
}
```

Comment: On jsp page in form tag modelAttribute will access as controller method parameter. Like you did in form u set modelAttribute as "userAccount" so in controller access that parameter.